# How do I disable hard mode in terraria mobile

Tags: terraria-mobile

Is it possible to revert Hardmode? I tried searching through the settings in creating a character and character settings.

Comment: Please view my edit. I believe it is more relevant to what you were asking

Answer (score 1):

No. [Hardmode](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hardmode), once activated in a world by killing the Wall of Flesh is irreversible. It is only in that world, however, so going to a non-Hardmode world to get powerful enough loot to survive is good idea.

EDIT:

If you are refering to a *Hardcore* character, that is also irreversible.